# i can't get more xamarin components - Uhandled Activation Error

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

When I try to login to Xamarin account by visual studio 2017 community i got 
Uhandled Activation Error
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Components is moving to NuGet

https://blog.xamarin.com/hello-nuget-new-home-xamarin-components/